# Algorithm2e: framed environment shifts line numbers

Tags: vertical-alignment, algorithm2e, framed

I want to have a box in my algorithm, and for that I'm using `framed` environment. However, it also shifts line numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vlined,ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    aaa
    \begin{framed}
    bbb
    \end{framed}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I vertically align line numbers? `\Indm` shifts the code, not the line numbers. `\DecMargin` doesn't apply to individual lines.
I don't mind using another package/environment instead of `framed` if you can recommend one: my only requirement is to have a box around a block of code.
I don't mind hardcoding the indentations if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `algorithm2e` uses `\llap` put the line numbers in a box of width zero, with the numbers plus their space from the algorithm, sticking out to the left of this box. This code patch adds more space to the left.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vlined,ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{framed}


%*****************************************% added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlength{\nummargin} % move line numbers to the margin
\setlength{\nummargin}{2ex}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\algocf@printnl}{\kern\skiplinenumber}{\kern\dimexpr\skiplinenumber +\nummargin+1ex }{}{}
\makeatother
%*****************************************

\begin{document}    

\begin{algorithm}
    aaa
    {\parindent-\nummargin\begin{framed}% changed <<<<
            bbb 
                
            ccc
    \end{framed}}
    ddd
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Used with `algorithm2e.sty    2017/07/18 v5.2`

**UPDATE** after follow-up up question

The command `\patchcmd` (package `etoolbox`)  allows to change a portion of a macro command.

```
\patchcmd{<command to patch>}{<code to be replaced>}{<new code>}{<message if success>}{<message if failure>}
```

The macro `\algocf@printnl` (line #1644 of `algorithm2e.sty`) generates the line numbers. The patch used in this example adds more space between the line number and the text by changing the `\kern`.
`\kern` is a TeX primitive used  to insert a non-breakable space.

Comment: Thank you very much! If possible, can you please explain what happens in line `\patchcmd{...}`? Or where I should look to undrestand what's going on there?

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you for your feedback!. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: THank you very much for the update!

Comment: By any chance, do you know how to handle nested boxes?

Comment: @Dmitry To help other readers please ask a new question.